# Constructing/borrowing of complex scientific/technological/financial vocabulary in Esperanto

Tags: borrowing, vocabulary, esperanto, word-formation, derivation

Most Esperanto scientific, some technology-specific, or financial dictionaries available online cover vast range, but mostly old terminology that was around for many years.  How does one translate or borrow (loan) new words that appear (very rapidly) for example in IT industry, finances, or adjacent highly volatile areas, in those cases not covered by standard [affix rules](http://donh.best.vwh.net/Esperanto/affixes.html) of Esperanto?

**Example**: I once noticed that "CPU stepping level", often used (as a noun) as simply *stepping*, was translated as *tretante*, which is obviously wrong (nouns must end in *-o*).  I started to think how to properly translate it.  Despite its simplicity, etymology of this English word is quite [complex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stepping_level): notice how two completely different nouns are formed from the original *step*: *stepper* (machine) and *stepping* (in the context of CPU/IC, kind of a version number).  While transition from *paŝo* (step) to *paŝilo* (stepper as a machine) can be more or less straightforward, further transformation (stepping as indirect result of stepper complete work, generation thereof) is not.  The closest candidates are:

- Category suffixes *-aĵ* and *-ec*
- Noun suffix *-id* (if at all possible)

*-aĵ* shows a concrete, tangible manifestation of the root (aĵo = a thing), but *stepping* is not that of *step* or even *stepper*.  It denotes something which was noticed as convenient, distinct reference point, akin to revision or version (edition), yet clearly related to the *stepper* machine and the way it works.

*-ec* shows a quality or characteristic defined by the root (eco = a characteristic, quality), but it normally applies to adjectives, not nouns; *paŝeco* would rather refer to some property of the machine, or the process itself (e.g. certain operational parameter).

*-id* denotes the offspring of the creature defined in the root.  Usually used for living creatures like kittens (*katido*), but also for halogenic salts (*klorido*).  It is unclear if it can be used (and be understandable) elsewhere (*paŝido* or *paŝilido* both do not exactly make much sense to me).

More and more English nouns appear which end in *-ing* and, unlike *casting* or *screening*, derived as result of some intricate procedure, or interpretation of its results, with no direct and simple relationship to the root, or had significantly evolved over time (e.g. *marketing* and other financial words like *futures [contract, exchange]*).  Are there any guidelines or somewhat general rules available for constructing coherent Esperanto equivalents of these nouns (ending in *-o*) for special, complicated cases like these?

Comment: I see; I was not clear indeed. I _do not_ seek translation/localization help, especially for a single word: Esperanto inherently allows to come up with adequate translation easily and correctly in most cases. What I'm wondering about is [word derivation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivation_(linguistics)) and [conversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_(word_formation)) practices of Esperanto in certain complicated language usage scenarios. I've augmented my question to make it more linguistics-related.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this question. I also find @bytebuster's logic to contain a nonsequitur in that the two qualities ascribed to the question do not lead to unanswerability. They may arguable lead to being off-topic, but I believe it's on topic to ask about word formation and derivation both as prescribed for an artificial language and as actually occurs in practice.

Comment: @hippietrail My comment was about original wording of this question. After the OP has changed it (see revision #2), I have casted my sincere vote to re-open it. Let me remove my first comment as it is no longer applicable.